# Find a function that matches the following conditions.

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

Find a function that matches the following conditions.

(a) $f(x)$ is continuous for all real numbers

(b) $f(0)$ = 3

(c) For all real numbers $x$, $f(x) = f(x/2)$

This is from a past paper, and the answer has been given as the following steps:

1. $f(a) = ... = f(a/2n)$
2. $f(a)$ = lim as n approaches infintiy $f(a)$ = lim as n approaches infinity of $f(a/2n)$
3. $f$(lim as n approaches infinity of $\frac{a}{2n}$ therefore $f$ is continuous
4. $f(0) = 3$

My question arises due to poor printing of my answer book. In step 1 is $f(a/2n)$ the correct step or should it be $(f(\frac{a}{2^n})$? If so could you please explain why? Because for both possibilities I can't seem to figure out why that's a step in proving the continuity. I'm sorry for the very elementary question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given that  $$f(x)=f(x/2)\ \ \ \ \ \text{ for all }\ \ \ \ x.$$ We can replace $x$ by any number we want and get a new valid equality.

Let's put $x/2$ instead of $x$. We get $f(x/2)=f(x/2^2)$.

Again $f(x/2)=f(x/2^2)$ is true for all $x$. Replace $x$ by $x/2$ again. We get $f(x/2^2)=f(x/2^3)$.

Continuing in this way we get $$f(x)=f(x/2)=f(x/2^2)=...=f(x/2^n)$$ for all $n$. The continuity is used to do $$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x)=\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x/2^n)=f(\lim_{n\to\infty}x/2^n)}_{\text{Continuity is what allows this step.}}=f(0)=3$$

Comment: I see! But could you please explain how $2^n$ as the denominator with its exponent n increasing prove the continuity for all of x? Wait, is the n increasing to infinity done to make sure it eventually becomes $f(0)$?

Comment: @Eric You don't prove the continuity. You are given it in condition (a).

Comment: I'm sorry, last question, I get that the continuity allowed that last step as you so graciously underlined in your answer, but my question is what justifies us to add the exponent $n$ to the 2 in step one, when there was only mention of $f(x/2)$ in the conditions given by the question? Thank you!

Comment: If anyone can answer my question in the comment above, please do!

Comment: @Eric Re-read the answer above.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I get it now! Thank you so much!